# Difference between Gradle's terms evaluation and execution

Tags: build, gradle, execution, evaluation

I am new to Gradle build tool and now I am reading the User Guide, but can't understand fully the difference between evaluation and execution phases.

In configuration phase project objects are configured and DAG is created, but we have **afterEvaluate**, so what is evaluate here? Evaluation of the tasks dependencies or what?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As you have seen in documentation, there are three phases: Initialization, Configuration and Execution. Each step is traversed from root project down to subprojects for multi project builds. The afterEvaluate is useful in the root gradle file of a multi project build when you want to configure specific items based on the configuration made in subprojects.

Say you want to add a task for all subprojects that have a specific plugin defined. If you add to your root project:

```
subprojects {subProject ->
  if ( subProject.plugins.hasPlugin('myplugin')){
    subProject.task('newTask')<<{
      println "This is a new task"
    }
  }
}
```

This task will never be added since the root project is configured before the subprojects.
Adding afterEvaluate will solve this for you:

```
subprojects {subProject ->
  afterEvaluate{
    if ( subProject.plugins.hasPlugin('myplugin')){
      subProject.task('newTask')<<{
        println "This is a new task"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So **afterEvaluate** can configure some items after the rest configuration has been done? Something like doLast, but not for alone tasks,**afterEvaluate** put its  config after other configuration and before execution. So evaluation executes after a the end of configuration and before execution? Am I right?

Comment: Yes you are right. Besides `project.afterEvaluate`, which runs after a particular project has been configured, there is also a `gradle.projectsEvaluated` hook that runs after all projects have been configured.

Comment: "this tasl will never be added since the root project is configured before  the subprojects". I can't understand how that statement is relevant.

Comment: It's all about timing. If you try to configure things before they exist, there will be problems.